# Кастомная анимация в ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation

Я использую `ItemTouchHelper` для реализации фичи "удаление по свайпу". Знаю, что есть и другие способы сделать это, но читал что использование `ItemTouchHelper` - самый удобный и современный, а в добавок он не требует сторонних библиотек.

Вот так мое приложение ведет себя в настоящий момент. Как только на экране не остается элеметов - показывается картинка посередине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Корзина реализована фрагментом [ShoppingCartFragment.java](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/java/com/webtrust/tennosushi/fragments/ShoppingCartFragment.java), а адаптер для `RecyclerView`, который используется в этом фрагменте, реализован в [ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/java/com/webtrust/tennosushi/adapters/ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java). Извиняюсь, что код выкладываю не сюда, а на гитхаб - это из-за ограничения на 30000 символов. Я поместил весь свой проект в [отдельную ветку](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/tree/swipe_animation_StackOverflow) для StackOverflow, чтобы этот код в будущем не пропал.

**ВОПРОСЫ**

1. Почему при свайпе у элемента сверху и снизу появляются края?

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Почему красный фон, оставленный после удаления элемента в середине списка, аккуратно уменьшается по высоте (гифка 1), в то время как после удаления элемента анимации изменения высоты не происходит, если этот элемент был единственный в списке (гифка 2).

   [image: Гифка 1]   [image: Гифка 2]
3. Как удалить черные тени во время анимации появления кнопки UNDO (т.е. когда оа выезжает слева)? Мне кажется, что нужно изменить стандартную анимацию появления кнопки UNDO, которая зарыта где-то в ItemTouchHelper, но я не знаю где это сделать (т.е. какой метод за это отвечает)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. **САМЫЙ ВАЖНЫЙ ВОПРОС** - Как задать свою анимацию для объектов, которые расположены "позади" элемента, сдвинутого свайпом? Например, в Gmail используется совершенно другая анимация появления кнопки UNDO:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любым советам, ссылкам и предложениям. Не стесняйтесь задать вопрос, если я где-то непонятно выразился.

Comment: У recyclerview есть itemAnimator, также гугл написал defaultItemAnimator, я в своей задачи просто скопировал их код из этого класса , он файнал вроде, и переопределил анимации какие нужно было

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Этот ответ будет дополнен позже.***

И так, вот что мне удалось узнать по поводу вопросов выше. Не забывайте что я ссылаюсь на код проекта в соответствующей [ветке](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/tree/swipe_animation_StackOverflow) на моем гитхабе.

1) Мне кажется, что тут возможны две причины: либо это связанно с ItemDecorator'ом, который используется для RecyclerView ([ShoppingCartFragment.java](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/java/com/webtrust/tennosushi/fragments/ShoppingCartFragment.java), строка 344), либо мы не видим тени у элементов RecyclerView т.к. между ними нет расстояния и тени просто "прячутся" под смежными элементами списка. У меня нет сейчас времени и возможности это выяснить, так что вопрос пока можно считать открытым. Я дополню ответ, как только выясню в чем конкретно заключается такое поведение теней.

2) Это связано с тем, что "анимация", которую вы видите - иллюзия. На самом деле красный фон не изменяет себя по высоте - его просто перекрывает элемент снизу. В этом легко убедиться, если добавить в разметку отступы.

[image: Анимация замедлена в 10 раз]

Чтобы устранить такое убогое поведение, достаточно привязать верхний и нижний края красного фона к верхнему и нижнему элементу списка соответственно

```
    /**
     * Подготавливает объект {@link ItemTouchHelper} и его колбэк
     * {@link android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback} для прослушивания
     * свайпов и реализации основных графических эфектов свайпов (например, таких как красный фон
     * позади элемента, сдвигаемого свайпом)
     */
    private void setUpItemTouchHelper() {
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            /** Фон, который показывается "за" элеметом при свайпе */
            Drawable background;
            /** Рисунок, информирующей пользователя, что сделаый иим свайп приведет к удалеию элемета */
            Drawable deleteMark;
            /** Отступы {@link #deleteMark}'а */
            int xMarkMargin;
            /** Флаг того, что метод {@link #init()} был вызван */
            boolean initiated;

            /** Инициализирует ресурсы графики, требуемые для свайпа. Например, {@link #background} */
            private void init() {
                background = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
                deleteMark = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_delete_24dp); // Получение ресурса "мусорной корзины"
                deleteMark.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // Фильтр, которй делает корзину белой
                xMarkMargin = (int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.swipe_delete_mark_margin);
                initiated = true;
            }

            /**
             * Метод, обязательный для реализации, но не использующийся в данном приложении.
             * Нужен для реализации "drag & drop".
             * @param recyclerView RecyclerView, к которому прикрепляется нащ ItemTouchHelper
             * @param viewHolder ViewHolder (т.е. элемент списка), который подвергается перетаскиванию
             *                   по инициативе пользователя
             * @param target ViewHolder, над которым перетаскивается текущий активный элемент
             * @return True, если viewHolder перемещен в позицию адаптера элемета target.
             */
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Возвращает допустимые направления свайпа для данного объекта viewHolder.
             * Эти допустимые направления свайпов настраиваются либо в кострукторе, либо в {@link #setDefaultSwipeDirs(int)}.
             * @param recyclerView {@link RecyclerView}, к которому прикрепляется наш {@link ItemTouchHelper}
             * @param viewHolder {@link RecyclerView.ViewHolder}, для которого запашивается направление свайпа
             * @return Логическое сложение допустимых свайпов (допустимый свайп представляет собой одну из костан группы "Direction Flag")
             */
            @Override
            public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                // Порядковый номер элемента, по которому пользователь хочет сделать свайп
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                // Запретить свайп, если появился красный фон, ожидающий нажатие кнопки Undo
                if (rvAdapter.undoOn && rvAdapter.isPendingRemoval(position)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            }

            /**
             * Вызывается когда свайп доведен до конца и палец пользователя убран с экрана.
             * Помещает в очередь на удаление или удаляет элемет списка в зависимости от
             * значения флага {@link ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter#undoOn}.
             * @param viewHolder
             * @param swipeDir
             */
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                // Порядковый номер элемента, по которому был сделан свайп
                int swipedPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (rvAdapter.undoOn) {
                    rvAdapter.pendingRemoval(swipedPosition); // Добавить элемент в список элементов, ожидающих удаление
                } else {
                    rvAdapter.remove(swipedPosition); // Просто удалить элемент
                }
            }

            /**
             * Вызывается для отрисовки всех объектов позади элемента списка, который сдвинули свайпом.
             * Подробнее:
             * <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onChildDraw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20boolean)"></a>
             *
             * <p>
             * Этот метод так же вызывается, когда элемент сдвинут, палец убран, но список плавно
             * "задвигает" сдвинутый элемент. При этом viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() дает -1.
             * </p>
             *
             * @param c {@link Canvas}, на котором RecyclerView рисует то, что ему скажут
             * @param recyclerView {@link RecyclerView}, к которому прикрепляется наш {@link ItemTouchHelper}
             * @param viewHolder {@link RecyclerView.ViewHolder}, который анимируется из-за действий пользователя, или сам по себе
             * @param dX Величина горизонтального смещения (отностительно "нормальной" позиции элемента), вызванного действием пользователя
             * @param dY Величина вертикального смещения (отностительно "нормальной" позиции элемента), вызванного действием пользователя
             * @param actionState Тип взаимодействия во View. Это может быть ACTION_STATE_DRAG или ACTION_STATE_SWIPE.
             * @param isCurrentlyActive True, когда анимация вызвана дейсвтиями юзера и False, когда анимация работает "сама по себе"
             */
            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                // View, по которому был сделан свайп
                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                int pos = viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(); // TODO: getAdapterPosition()

                // Этот if сработает, когда элемент сдвинут, палец убран, но список плавно "задвигает" сдвинутый элемент
                if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == -1) {
                    // not interested in those
                    return;
                }

                // Проверка на то, были ли инииализированы графические ресурсы для рисования фона и прочих объектов
                if (!initiated) {
                    init();
                }

                // Вьюха предыдущего элемента (null, если ее абсолютно нет на экране)
                View previousView = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(pos-1);
                // Вьюха следующего элемента (null, если ее абсолютно нет на экране)
                View nextView = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(pos+1);

                // Получение координат вьюх элементов списка
                int[] nextViewLocation = new int[2]; // Координаты следующей (за свайпнутой) вьюхи
                int[] itemViewLocation = new int[2];  // Координаты свайпнутой вьюхи
                int[] previousViewLocation = new int[2];  // Координаты предыдущей вьюхи
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp1 = null; // Инициализация отступов для следующей ...
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp2 = null; // ... и предыдущей вьюхи

                if (itemView != null) // Если элемент есть на экране
                    itemView.getLocationInWindow(itemViewLocation); // TODO: Как будет вести себя этот кусок кода, если анимации в процессе, а вьюхи нет на экране. Этого можно досич если во время анимации пролистать список вниз
                if (previousView != null) { // Если предыдущей элемент есть на экране (хотя бы частично)
                    previousView.getLocationInWindow(previousViewLocation); // Получить координаты предыдущего элемента
                    lp2 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) previousView.getLayoutParams(); // Получить отступы предыдущего элемента
                }
                if (nextView != null) { // Если следущющий элемент есть на экране (хотя бы частично)
                    nextView.getLocationInWindow(nextViewLocation); // Получить координаты следующего элемента
                    lp1 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) nextView.getLayoutParams(); // Получить отступы следующего элемента
                }

                // Вычисления координат высот элеметов
                int cordTop;
                int cordBottom;
                ActionBar ab = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

                // Вычисление высоты статус бара и action бара
                // TODO: Не зннаю как будет работать для полноэкранного режима. Имеет смысл добавить проверку в if ниже
                int resultStatusBar = 0;
                int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
                if (resourceId > 0) {
                    resultStatusBar = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                }
                int barsOffset = resultStatusBar+ab.getHeight(); // Смещение для канвы по оси Y

                if (previousView != null) {
                    cordTop = previousViewLocation[1]+previousView.getHeight()- barsOffset+lp2.topMargin+lp2.bottomMargin;
                    //Log.d( String.valueOf( previousView.getTop() ), String.valueOf( cordTop ));
                } else {
                    cordTop = itemView.getTop();
                }

                if (nextView != null) {
                    //Log.d( String.valueOf( nextView.getTop() ), String.valueOf( nextViewLocation[1] ));
                    //Log.d( "a", "1");
                    cordBottom = nextViewLocation[1] - barsOffset-lp1.topMargin-lp1.bottomMargin;
                } else {
                    //Log.d( "a", "2");
                    cordBottom = itemView.getBottom(); // TODO: Учитывает ли getBottom отступы?
                }

                background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, cordTop, itemView.getRight(), cordBottom);
                background.draw(c);

                // Рисование иконки удаления
                // Замер элемета, по которому был сдела свайп
                int itemHeight = itemView.getBottom() - itemView.getTop(); // Растояние в пикселях!
                // Замер размеов иконки удаления
                int intrinsicWidth = deleteMark.getIntrinsicWidth(); // Слово "Intrinsic" можно просто отбросить
                int intrinsicHeight = deleteMark.getIntrinsicWidth();

                // Определение позиции икоки на красном фоне
                int xMarkLeft = itemView.getRight() - xMarkMargin - intrinsicWidth;
                int xMarkRight = itemView.getRight() - xMarkMargin;
                int xMarkTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight)/2;
                int xMarkBottom = xMarkTop + intrinsicHeight;

                // Определяет размеры квадратой области за сдвинутым элеметом, где будет нарисован xMark
                deleteMark.setBounds(xMarkLeft, xMarkTop, xMarkRight, xMarkBottom);
                deleteMark.draw(c); // Рисует иконку удаления

                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
```

Имейте ввиду, что получить координаты красного фона при помощи getTop() и getBottom() нельзя (по крайней мере, у меня не вышло). Так что я делаю это используя getLocationInWindow()

3) Что бы ответить на этот вопрос нужно понимать, что View, которую вы видите на экране ДО свайпа и ПОСЛЕ - на самом деле одна и та же View. Эта View включает в себя элементы для двух состояний сразу, но по умолчанию видимо только одно состояние - которое присуще View до свайпа. Когда происходит свайп, мы программно скрываем вложенные View для состояния "до свайпа" и отображаем View, которые должны появиться после свайпа (Например, кнопку Undo). Это можно найти в файле [ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/java/com/webtrust/tennosushi/adapters/ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java) на строке 157. Но лучше показать на картинке внутреннее устройство элемента списка, чем объяснять словами ([shopping_cart_item.xml](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/res/layout/shopping_cart_item.xml):
[image: Кнопка Undo скрыта, т.к. она будет показана только когда все остальные View элемента списка будут иметь видимость GONE]
[image: Элемент списка глазами пользователя ДО свайпа]
Чтобы избавить от теней - я просто отключал их в коде:

```
    /**
     * Задает значения полям, хранящие ссылки на элементы GUI (например, для {@link #recyclerView})
     * @param view UI, которое вернул метод {@link #onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)}
     * @param savedInstanceState Если не равно NULL, то фрагмент восстановился из предыдущего
     *                           сохраненного состояния. Этот объект  и есть его предыдущее состояние.
     */
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //...

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator() {
            /**
             * Отвечает за анимацию "выдвижения" кнопки Undo (и, возможно, за что-то еще)
             * @param oldHolder Элемент списка, который подвергся изменению
             * @param newHolder Элемент списка, который получился из-за произошедших изменений
             * @param fromX Левый край oldHolder
             * @param fromY Вверхий край oldHolder
             * @param toX Левый край newHolder
             * @param toY Вверхий край newHolder
             * @return True, если позже ожидается (запрашивается) вызов {@link #runPendingAnimations()}, иначе - false
             */
            @Override
            public boolean animateChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder,
                                         int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
                // Получение ссылок на элемет CardView в oldHolder и newHolder
                CardView oldHolderCardView = (CardView) oldHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_card_view);
                CardView newHolderCardView = (CardView) newHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_card_view);

                // Сохранение старых значение elevation (на свякий случай)
                // СОХРАНЕНИЕ СТАРЫХ ЗНАЧЕНИЙ И ПОСЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ ИХ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ ВЕДЕТ ТОМУ, ЧТО ТЕНЬ НЕ БУДЕТ УБИРАТЬСЯ!
                //float oldHolderElevation = oldHolderCardView.getCardElevation();
                //float newHolderElevation = newHolderCardView.getCardElevation();

                // Убираем тень при выдвижении кнопки Undo
                oldHolderCardView.setCardElevation(0);
                newHolderCardView.setCardElevation(0);

                // Запускаем стандартную анимацию
                boolean returnedBool = super.animateChange(oldHolder, newHolder, fromX, fromY, toX, toY);

                // Возвращаем стандартных elevation
                //oldHolderCardView.setCardElevation(oldHolderElevation);
                //newHolderCardView.setCardElevation(newHolderElevation);

                // Возвращем результат стандартной анимации
                return returnedBool;
            }
        });
```

4) Ответа на этот вопрос у меня пока нет. Даже не знаю где копать. Я надеюсь, что вернусь это к этому вопросу позже и обязательно дополню этот ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Ну и каковы результаты поисков?